# If statement in concat SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ISNULL(CONCAT(full_name,' ' ,'( ',(aff_bus) ),'('),' ) ') AS shnames,contactrecord_id 
FROM contactrecord
ORDER BY shnames ASC
```

[image]

I'm showing the `aff_bus` column in the parentheses but I don't want the parentheses if the `aff_bus` column is blank. How can I remove the parentheses if the `aff_bus` column is blank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CASE to check if `aff_bus` is null or not

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN aff_bus IS NULL THEN full_name
       WHEN aff_bus = '' THEN full_name
       ELSE CONCAT(full_name, '(', aff_bus, ')') 
       END as shshames,
  contactrecord_id
FROM contactrecord
ORDER BY shnames ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for this, the aff_buss column is blank and not null so i modified this to:
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN aff_bus ='' THEN full_name
       ELSE CONCAT(full_name, ' ( ', aff_bus, ' ) ') 
       END as shnames,
  contactrecord_id
  from contactrecord
and it works great, thanks again

Comment: Ok, I saw it said blank but the ISNULL fooled me, if you want you can of course have both a CASE for '' and IS NULL

Answer (score 4):

Make use of the fact that "adding" with `NULL` returns `NULL`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(full_name, '') + ISNULL(' ( ' + aff_bus + ' )', '') AS shnames, contactrecord_id 
FROM contactrecord
ORDER BY shnames ASC
```

Comment: thanks for this, what if the aff_bus column is blank?

Comment: Well, then you still get empty brakets… try `NULLIF(aff_bus, '')` instead of `aff_bus`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use case statement to check column is null or blank.

   ```
   SELECT (CASE WHEN AFF_BUS IS NOT NULL AND AFF_BUS != '' 
            THEN  CONCAT(FULL_NAME,' ( ',aff_bus, ' ) ')
            ELSE  CONCAT (FULL_NAME,'')
        END) AS shnames, CONTACTRECORD_ID FROM CONTACTRECORD ORDER BY shnames ASC ;
   ```